# MinGW C++, multiple definition of `isspace'

Tags: c++, compilation, mingw, release, mingw32

I'm having this really weird issue when i'm trying to compile my code in release mode using mingw32-g++.

```
||=== Build: Release in Spel (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
c:\program files(x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\libmsvcrt.a(dsnos00652.o)|| multiple definition of `isspace'|
obj\Release\assetreader.o:c:\program files(x86)\codeblocks\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.7.1\..\..\..\..\include\ctype.h|162|first defined here|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|
```

I have no idea what to do... I've tried moving every single #include tag from the assetreader.ccp file (which is the only thing mentioned by name). When i build in debug it's fine.

The only place i included ctype.h i've removed. I am however using the glew library which runs this code (although deleting it makes no difference)

```
/* <ctype.h> */
#if (defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(__BORLANDC__)) && !defined(_WCHAR_T_DEFINED)
typedef unsigned short wchar_t;
#  define _WCHAR_T_DEFINED
#endif
```

And i haven't created anything named isspace myself, i only use it in a few lines of code anyway.

Very grateful for any help i can get, i don't know if it's my fault or a bug of some sort.

Comment: I've often had some weird errors with code blocks. I would suggest often cleaning the project. I'm not saying it will solve your problem but it did help me from time to time when I was still using this IDE

Comment: Thanks, i've done that already a couple of times. May i ask what IDE you are using now instead?

Comment: I use no IDE at all. A text editor like sublime and I compile with the terminal and command lines.  If you have removed all the files including the definition that is said to be given more than once you shouldn't get that error anymore. Try compiling with command lines and let me know what the output is please

Comment: It's odd that the linker is searching inside a library for a name that's defined in a object file. It's also a little bit odd that `isspace()` isn't being inlined in `assetreader.cpp`, but I guess it happens.  You might want to post the exact command line(s) that Code::Blocks is using to compile `assetreader.cpp` and to link the program.  It would be good if you could replicate this problem building from the command line - I think that makes it easier to troubleshoot.

Comment: Incredibly late response LBesancon, i'm sorry for that. How to i compile with command line? Do you want to see the build log, is that it?